# Exposing Native Device APIs to Web Apps

Tags: javascript, c#, android, ios, progressive-web-apps

There are a lot of ways to develop an app nowadays. You can create a full native app, hybrid app, pwa or website. There are probably some formats of apps I didn't mention however that's besides the point. The last two decades have proven that smartphones are the way most of the people(users) are interacting with apps and that's clearly also how they want to interact all the time literally all the time! Developers(wizards) have been working to meet those demands by creating solutions like .Net blazor, Xamarin, Vue, Angular, ect to meet the demand for apps and their development. Currently app stores from Google and Apple are the way apps are distributed only for use to pay them a cut of our app revenue so we look to the web. When we want to create a highly secure app (server-side) we look to the web. When we want to support most operating systems we look to the web. I assume you get the point. only there is one thing that stands in the way and that is excess to the users native device APIs. There are alot of native APIs that are already available in HTML5 only we know that those aren't the specific ones we need for the app we develop. So what are the ways we can expos native device APIs to web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Cordova Plugins: https://cordova.apache.org. If you want to expose API into web, you just should write some player application (web browser) witch will translates JS commands into native API callbacks. To achieve it, you can use [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler).
[Here](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/ios-wkwebview-communication-using-javascript-and-swift-ee077e0127eb) you can find an example.
It is not very complicated, but if you want to cover all API, it will very complicated code.
Also, you forget about one coin of a web application: long time of a response, especially with low internet connection. I do not think that is a good idea.

Comment: low internet connection could definitly be a obstacle however for the application I'm creating users will be in a place that will have a good and quick wifi connection when they use it. Cordova still wraps the web views in a native application and that is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you need to expose native API, your should to write native application. But your application will be like to internet browser with extended java API, which will translate JS functions, variables, classes into native functions, variables and classes. As I understand, you want to do it in Safari, it is not possible. Safari does not provide such JS API.